# Apache HBase Replication for Failover

Tags: hadoop, nosql, hbase, bigdata

Apache HBase:Replication:Shall the Slave/Replication cluster used for fail over handling as well instead of data recovery alone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. HBase Replication can serve as a disaster recovery solution and can contribute to provide higher availability or fail over as well. I am assuming that you have already gone through this **[page](http://hbase.apache.org/replication.html)** which talks about HBase Replication.